# Data and Time format in c++

Tags: c++

I need to convert Date time in 17 byte format.

The format is

```
MMDDYYYY HH:MM:SS
```

in ASCII.

Example date and time: 01212009 09:38:57

**Hexadecimal format**

```
0x30    0x31    0x32    0x31    0x32    0x30    0x30    0x39
0x20    0x30    0x39    0x3A    0x33    0x38    0x3A    0x35    0x37
```

the problem is how to convert this 01212009 09:38:57 in to hex format.I need to send this date timeover network.

Comment: Achieving? Converting to? Expected inputs? This question is vague.

Comment: What format do you *have* and what format do you *want*. Show us the function you're going to call.

Comment: And also, what have you tried already? Lastly, please tag as homework if it is as such.

Comment: what are you having trouble with? the hex data and it's string representation in your question are identical.

Comment: I wanted the logic to convert 01212009 09:38:57 in to 17 byte format.

Comment: @Chris_vr, `std::copy(date_str.begin(), date_str.end(), std::back_inserter(dest))` - where `date` is a `std::vector<char>` - seems easy enough to me..

Comment: @Chris_vr: but `01212009 09:38:57` is already in 17 byte format

Comment: what is Dest here Nim?will it convert 01212009 09:38:57 to Hexadecimal format?

Comment: correct  Anton Semenov.but the problem is how hexadecimal fomrat is created from the ascii.see i got this from my client But i not able to understand.how 01212009 09:38:57 is converted in to 0x30 0x 31 0x32 .. etc.

Comment: @Chris_vr: there is no conversion to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hexadecimal values that you posted are exactly the ascii values for the string that you posted, `01212009 09:38:57`.
There's really no conversion done from that string to the hex values in your example.

so if you have this:

```
const char* dateStr = "01212009 09:38:57";
```

and you print it like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < strlen(dateStr); ++i)
{
    printf("%x\t", dateStr[i]);
}
```

(or something like that, anyway)
you'll get basically those values.
you're just displaying them as their hexadecimal values instead of their character representation.

Answer (score 1):

Im actually didnt know on which platform you are working. I think `itoa` function should exists on all platforms as part of standard C++ library. Use it to conver char value to hex. Just set `radix` parameter to 16

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing form with representation.

Just because we conventionally represent "raw bytes" in hexadecimal format doesn't mean that they "exist" that way.

Whether you display the data as the ASCII string "01212009 09:38:57" or as a list of broken-down individual byte values, it's *still the same data*, and it's *still 17 bytes*.

Consequently, there is no conversion to be done here.